# Why does waffle dough get dark?

Tags: dough, pancakes, waffle

Always when I make waffles or pancakes the dough of it gets dark after a few hours. It looks like having black sprinkles.

Why is that and how long can I still use it?

The ingredients I use for waffles are:

- 250g sugar
- 250g margarine
- 500g flour
- 5 eggs
- 500g milk
- baking powder
- a shot of rum

And for pancakes I use almost the same

- sugar
- flour
- eggs
- milk
- baking powder

[image: dough]

It will get darker - it is still pretty fresh.

Comment: That's odd. Can you tell us exactly what you put into the batter? A picture would be great too, if possible.

Comment: I get this very often when I make Yorkshire Pudding batter (very similar recipes). I seem to recall it's down to oxidisation of the bran, but I can't find a source for that. It's never done any noticeable harm.

Comment: I concur with Elendil, there is no reason *not* to use the batter, it's fine as long as you use safe practices (mind your "danger-zone"). I'm still a bit flummoxed about the color change. What kind of flour are you using?

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I use normal wheat flour.

Comment: Those just look like air bubbles.

Answer (score -3):

This is strange. I've never made waffles before, but that pancake recipe is almost exactly the one I use, except for the baking powder. If it goes dark soon after preparing the mix, it is most likely a chemical reaction between two or more of the ingredients. It should still be perfectly safe to use, so don't worry about the discolouration. :)

Comment: Is this anything more than idle speculation? We're looking for answers that are based on well-known facts or personal experiences. If you've never made waffles, and never experienced this issue yourself when making pancake batter, then this answer isn't helpful.

Comment: @Aaronut The fact that this has never happened to me when making pancakes, shows that it can't be a common thing, and I did research this problem and [here is one of my sources.](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11374/26139) I have given a reason why the problem might have occurred and I can't see how else it might have happened. If you can think of a better reason, then why don't you post it.

Comment: That's not how it works here, or any other site on this network. Vague, incomplete, or poorly-substantiated answers are *supposed* to be downvoted and comments are largely a courtesy - no one is obligated to try to post a "better" answer. The biggest problem here is the overt assumption that it's safe, without any clear explanation (or understanding) of what the reaction is. *Of course* it's a chemical reaction - *everything* in cooking is a chemical reaction - but *what* reaction?