# Three day old pancake batter with grey spots

Tags: batter, pancakes

I know from experience and Googling that day-old carrot cake can result in green carrot bits due to oxidation but remains perfectly edible. Has the same thing happened to my pancake batter? Or are these grey spots speckled throughout mold? It doesn't smell nor taste off.

Comment: Can you link a picture?

Comment: Related post: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/buttermilk-pancake-mix-is-green

Comment: Shoot, I couldn't stop the wife's appetite. She went ahead and consumed it so no picture possible. 3 hours on and she's still alive so, anecdotally at least, it was either safe discoloration or ... a safe amount of mold? Heh.

Comment: @Didgeridrew Good find. I think this was just a chemical discoloration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the pancake batter is going bad and bacteria is developing. No mold is good. In a restaurant environment I would sometimes keep it over night in the fridge but not any longer. From a food safety standpoint, food should not be left out longer than 4 hours before being discarded. Just because it does not smell does not mean it is OK. Pancake batter is cheap so tossing it is no loss. If you are asking your question from a chemical reaction standpoint, I am sorry I can't help. But I do not think you would want to go to a restaurant and be served pancakes with grey spots.